# Why file does not including into controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed the **[package](https://packagist.org/packages/coinpaymentsnet/coinpayments-php)** from composer I am trying to include file from vendor folder into controller but it does not including.

Here is what I am trying

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use src\Coinpayments;
use src\keys;
class CoinController extends Controller
{

    public function DoIt(){
            $cps = new CoinPaymentsAPI();
        }
}
```

And this is in composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "coinpaymentsnet/coinpayments-php": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
```

In the result I am getting following error which is

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\CoinPaymentsAPI' not found

Comment: what's the package ?

Comment: @JoanMarcos it is this one https://packagist.org/packages/coinpaymentsnet/coinpayments-php

Comment: 1. You haden't provide useful (full) code, From where this "CoinPaymentsAPI" came? Class 'App\Http\Controllers\CoinPaymentsAPI' not found 2. You might including (using) wrong namespace

Comment: use the laravel https://github.com/kevupton/laravel-coinpayments/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

After a composer install it's advised to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

In the instructions from the package they tell you to include the following file:

```
require('/your_installation_path_to/src/CoinpaymentsAPI.php');
```

You aren't including it correctly, pretty sure your IDE is giving you errors.
It's probably, I found this information in the composer.json file included in the package:

```
use Coinpaymentsnet\CoinpaymentsAPI
```